# Which neural net architecture could solve the addition of all digits in a number to a single digit?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

This is a **hypothetical** problem that I would like to explore from the perspective of ML.

I have a number like 45624. If I add up all the digits until I have only one left, I'd do the following:

4 + 5 + 6 + 2 + 4 = 21

2 + 1 = 3

How could I use a neural net or any other technique to model that problem?

***IMPORTANT***:

1. **I know** I don't need a neural network or ML for this
2. **I know** multiple ways to solve this
3. This is **not** a real problem, just a hypothetical one which I want to explore from an ML perspective.

Comment: A simple recursive function get the job done rather fast, and the limit is the integer dtype. Why do you want to use a neural network?

Comment: You don't need a neural network for this.

Comment: @user2653663 I don't, I just want to explore it from that perspective. I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @RoshinRaphel, I know, this is a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the digits is a modulo 9 operation. So your problem is equivalent toto teach your network to perform a modulo.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380303/keras-making-a-neural-network-to-find-a-numbers-modulus) are some interesting elements of answers.